# Hidden left nav but visible account dashboard links in Magento

Tags: php, css, xml, magento

I'm working on a responsive website but I'm a complete PHP novice.

I've hidden the left nav for smaller screen sizes (phones/tablets) but this also hides the left nav from the Account Dashboard, which I need to be visible.

Ideally I'd like it to form part of the content at the top of the page below the main menu and header rather than sit on the left hand side due to space constrictions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to achieve this please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We would need a code example in order to give you proper advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at any code examples, one can assume:

- If the left nav is being hidden also on the Account dashboard, it is probably using the same class as in other sections, so you have to find a way to differentiate them so that the one on the Account page is not hidden.
- Also, if you want to display it on top of the content and below the header, you probably have to set its float status to none, as well as the content adjacent to it. This is assuming both blocks are positioned via floats.